# Android Relative layout Usage

Tags: android, android-layout

Suggest me on this
             I have to use some header and body part in android screen design, Can i use plain *Linear* layout for screen design or can i use *relative* layout or else both layout combined together.For the header bar im using a gradient image and application runs both in **vertical** and **horizontal** orientation.
 As of now im using **two main linear layouts** for the first one im using a height of 40 dp and for the second i just used 0dip is this a correct way of approach or i have change anything.

Comment: Your explication is not clear enough. post some graphic to help us understand. And of course you can use as many linearlayout and relative layout as you want. Just make sure to use proportion (%, dp, dpi) instead of px et fix dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linear-Linear, Linear-Relative or Relative-Relative. Anything you want.

Your question is hard to understand. From what i get, i think your approach is fine. **You should let the Screen design (second layout) use "match_parent". It will take up remaining part. For your header layout using "40dp" is fine.** I made app with Header, and i used this approach.

If in Header, you are adding images as well as TextView, it is advisable to use RelativeLayout. In the rest part, use however you need it.

Comment: if i use match_parent it shows warning so only i go for 0dip. ya you have got my point clearly

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix concept of `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`. `RelativeLayout` is preferred because it reduces extra lines as compared to `LinearLayout`. In `RelativeLayout` views are placed relative to each other i.e. **left, right, top and bottom** unlike `LinearLayout` where you can't place view in respect of some other view. Both have its own advantages. As Weight concept is not supported by `RelativeLayout` but `LinearLayout`.

Depending on the complexity of layout both are chosen. One thing to avoid is un-necessary nesting of layouts which reduces performance. I would recommend read concepts of `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` and weight first then you will be able to judge which layout to use on your own. Till then use `RelativeLayout` as it requires minimum number of lines.